# Tkinter - Passing variables between frames after askopenfilename?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, spyder

New to Tkinter. I've been at this for a few days now. I'm looking to pass the file path of an Mp4 video (retrieved using askopenfilename and a button) to another frame (where I grab the first frame and display it, so the user can select a ROI).

**UPDATED!** **MINIMAL, VIABLE EXAMPLE:** RUNNING THIS CODE, THE FILENAME CHOSEN DOES NOT DISPLAY ON THE SECOND FRAME (PROBLEM):

```
LARGE_FONT=("Verdana",12)

import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog 
from tkinter import *


filename = ''


class HRDetectorApp(tk.Tk): #in brackets, what the class inherits

    def __init__(self,*args,**kwargs): #this will always load when we run the program. self is implied args = unlimited vars. kwargs are keywords arguments (dictionaries)

        tk.Tk.__init__(self,*args,**kwargs)
        container = tk.Frame(self)

        container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True) #pack into top, fill into entire top space, and expand will expand into the whole window. fill into the area you packed.

        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1) #min size zero, weight is priority
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0,weight=1)

        self.frames = {}
        self.shared_data = {"filename": tk.StringVar()}

        for F in (StartPage, SelectROIPage):

            frame = F(container,self)

            self.frames[F] = frame

            frame.grid(row=0,column=0, sticky="nsew") #sticky = alignment + stretch, north south east west

        self.show_frame(StartPage)
        self.title("Heart Rate Detection")


    def show_frame(self,cont):
        frame=self.frames[cont]
        frame.tkraise()

    def get_page(self, page_class):
        return self.frames[page_class]



def openFile():
    root = tk.Tk()
    global filename 
    filename = filedialog.askopenfilename(title="Select an Mp4 Video", filetypes =(("Mp4 Files", "*.mp4"),))
    root.update_idletasks()
    print(filename)


class StartPage(tk.Frame):


    def __init__(self,parent,controller):
        self.controller = controller
        #global filename
        #filename = ""
        tk.Frame.__init__(self,parent)
        label = tk.Label(self,text="Start Page", font=LARGE_FONT)
        label.pack(pady=10,padx=10)
        self.filename = tk.StringVar()

        chooseFileButton = tk.Button(self,text="Upload a Video",command=openFile)
        chooseFileButton.pack()

        goButton = tk.Button(self,text ="Click me after you've uploaded a video!", command = lambda: controller.show_frame(SelectROIPage))
        goButton.pack()



class SelectROIPage(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self,parent,controller):

        tk.Frame.__init__(self,parent)
        label = tk.Label(self,text="Select a Region of Interest (R.O.I)", font=LARGE_FONT)
        label.pack(pady=10,padx=10)
        label = tk.Label(self, text = "selected file : " + filename)
        label.pack()



app = HRDetectorApp()
app.mainloop()
```

How to reproduce?

1. Click "Upload a video" and select an MP4 file.
2. Click "Click me after you've uploaded a video"

For some reason, the variable doesn't update after calling askopenfilename. I've tried to use global variables, using root.update, nothing has worked (see my attempts commented out)

*Any help is greatly appreciated, thank you!*

ORIGINAL CODE : thanks for your suggestions to simplify it :)

```
LARGE_FONT=("Verdana",12)

import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog 
from tkinter import *
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use("TkAgg")
from matplotlib.widgets import RectangleSelector
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg, NavigationToolbar2Tk
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cv2
import numpy as np
import sys
import time
from scipy import signal
import scipy.signal as signal
import selectinwindow


class HRDetectorApp(tk.Tk): #in brackets, what the class inherits

    def __init__(self,*args,**kwargs): #this will always load when we run the program. self is implied args = unlimited vars. kwargs are keywords arguments (dictionaries)

        tk.Tk.__init__(self,*args,**kwargs)
        container = tk.Frame(self)

        container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True) #pack into top, fill into entire top space, and expand will expand into the whole window. fill into the area you packed.

        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1) #min size zero, weight is priority
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0,weight=1)

        self.frames = {}
        self.shared_data = {"filename": tk.StringVar()}

        for F in (StartPage, SelectROIPage):

            frame = F(container,self)

            self.frames[F] = frame

            frame.grid(row=0,column=0, sticky="nsew") #sticky = alignment + stretch, north south east west

        self.show_frame(StartPage)
        self.title("Heart Rate Detection")


    def show_frame(self,cont):
        frame=self.frames[cont]
        frame.tkraise()

    def get_page(self, page_class):
        return self.frames[page_class]


#
#def openFile():
#    root = tk.Tk()
#    global filename 
#    root.filename = filedialog.askopenfilename(title="Select an Mp4 Video", filetypes =(("Mp4 Files", "*.mp4"),))
#    filename = root.filename 
#    root.update_idletasks()
#    #name = root.filename
#    
#    print(filename)


class StartPage(tk.Frame):


    def __init__(self,parent,controller):
        self.controller = controller
#        global filename
#        filename = ""
        tk.Frame.__init__(self,parent)
        label = tk.Label(self,text="Start Page", font=LARGE_FONT)
        label.pack(pady=10,padx=10)
        self.filename = tk.StringVar()

        chooseFileButton = tk.Button(self,text="Upload a Video",command=self.openFile)
        chooseFileButton.pack()

        goButton = tk.Button(self,text ="Click me after you've uploaded a video!", command = lambda: controller.show_frame(SelectROIPage))
        goButton.pack()

    def openFile(self):
        #root = tk.Tk()
        #global filename 
        #root.filename = filedialog.askopenfilename(title="Select an Mp4 Video", filetypes =(("Mp4 Files", "*.mp4"),))
       # filename = root.filename 
        self.filename.set(filedialog.askopenfilename(title="Select an Mp4 Video", filetypes =(("Mp4 Files", "*.mp4"),)))
        #root.update()
        #if filename == "":
            #root.after(1000,openFile(self))
        #name = root.filename

        print(self.filename.get())

**code to use rectangle selector for selecting ROI**

class SelectROIPage(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self,parent,controller):


        tk.Frame.__init__(self,parent)
        self.controller = controller
        startpg = self.controller.get_page(StartPage)
        file = startpg.filename.get() **THIS IS NOT UPDATING**
        label = tk.Label(self,text="Select a Region of Interest (R.O.I)", font=LARGE_FONT)
        label.pack(pady=10,padx=10)

        #file=filename

        **code to read image and display it (confirmed no errors here!)**



app = HRDetectorApp()
app.mainloop()
```

Comment: I know it's extra work, but please try to create a minimal reproducible example (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) rather than posting all of your code. It's easier to provide help, and you may solve your own problem in the process.

Answer (score 0):

In your methods you *reference* the global `filename`. But in the global scope you don't *create* `filename`.

If you were to do that (say just before `app = HRDetectorApp()`), it should work.

**Update**

Based on your MVE, this is what happens.

You are creating the `SelectROIPage` object in the `HRDetectorApp.__init__` method. *At that time*, the global variable `filename` points to an empty string.

What I would suggest it to create a *synthetic event* named e.g. `<<Update>>`.
In the `SelectROIPage` class, you define an `on_update` method that sets the label text. In `SelectROIPage.__init__`, you `bind` the `on_update` method to the `<<Update>>` event.

In the handler for clicking the `goButton` in `StartPage`, you call the `event_generate` method on the `SelectROIPage` object to send it the message. (This requires that the `StartPage` has an attribute for the `SelectROIPage` object)

Comment: Hey! Thanks so much for your suggestion. Gave that a shot and it didn't work :/ To clarify... I had SOME success using the global variable approach, however the variable would only update AFTER I close the app.

Comment: Judging by the imports, your code seems to be part of a larger program, most of which we don't see. Try to create a minimum viable example that exhibits the problematic behavior.

Comment: Hi just updated it with an example that shows the issue. Please have a look. thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

You are never updating the value in SelectROIPage. The page is instantiated once, and in that instantiation you initialize file to `''` with `file = startpg.filename.get()`, because this occurs before the button has been clicked when you create HRDetectorApp at `frame = F(container, self)`

When you click the button, it doesn't create a new frame, thus does not call so it is not updating, and the value is an empty string. You must somehow update the value when the first button is clicked.

I see a few options:

1. Use the same variable in both SelectROIPage and StartPage.
2. Update the variable when the button is clicked by extending readyForROI (a bit kludgy in my opinion)
3. Update the variable when the  ROI frame is shown using a binding (overkill, but see: [How would I make a method which is run every time a frame is shown in tkinter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35029188/how-would-i-make-a-method-which-is-run-every-time-a-frame-is-shown-in-tkinter))

If it were me, I would choose the first.

**UPDATE**
It's a bit trimmed but that's still not what I'd call a "minimum reproducible example".

I've edited your code a bit to accomplish what you're trying to do. I wanted to be able to point at a few other issues as well, so it's not quite minimal.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog 
from tkinter import *


class HRDetectorApp(tk.Tk): #in brackets, what the class inherits
    def __init__(self,*args,**kwargs): #this will always load when we run the program. self is implied args = unlimited vars. kwargs are keywords arguments (dictionaries)

        tk.Tk.__init__(self,*args,**kwargs)
        container = tk.Frame(self)

        container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True) #pack into top, fill into entire top space, and expand will expand into the whole window. fill into the area you packed.

        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1) #min size zero, weight is priority
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0,weight=1)

        self.frames = {}
        self.shared_data = {"filename": tk.StringVar()}

        for F in (StartPage, SelectROIPage):

            frame = F(container,self)

            self.frames[F] = frame

            frame.grid(row=0,column=0, sticky="nsew") #sticky = alignment + stretch, north south east west

        self.show_frame(StartPage)

    def show_frame(self,cont):
        frame=self.frames[cont]
        frame.tkraise()

    def get_page(self, page_class):
        return self.frames[page_class]


class StartPage(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self,  parent: tk.Widget, controller: HRDetectorApp):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self,parent)
        self.filename = controller.shared_data['filename'] # use the same object for filename here as in SelectROIPage
        tk.Button(self,text="Click me to pick a file", command=self.openFile).pack()
        tk.Button(self,text ="Click me after you've picked a file", command = lambda: controller.show_frame(SelectROIPage)).pack()

    def openFile(self):
        self.filename.set(filedialog.askopenfilename(title="Select a file"))
        print('filename in StartPage: {}'.format(self.filename.get()))


class SelectROIPage(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self,  parent: tk.Widget, controller: HRDetectorApp):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self,parent)
        self.filename = controller.shared_data['filename']
        tk.Label(self, text = "selected file : ").pack() # text assigns a permanent value
        tk.Label(self, textvariable=self.filename).pack()


app = HRDetectorApp()
app.mainloop()
```

So let's discuss this a little ...

1. First, you don't need to declare a variable `global` for this to work; that's more relevant to threading, i.e. a global variable can be accessed by all threads in the program.
2. You also instantiated a second root with root=tk.Tk(). It's important that you only ever have one root (instance of tk.Tk()) in your program.
3. You can call .grid() and .pack() directly after declaring a label if you don't need access to the widget in the future.
4. The actual issue you are having. What I meant was to provide a reference to the same variable in both classes. You were close with shared_data['filename'], but you never called or assigned it! Both classes have access to the variable (through controller), and thus they can access the value of the variable.
5. The benefit of using tkinter variables rather than pythong variables is callbacks and traces. If you use the `text` property of the label, it will assign a static string to the label. The second label iv'e created uses the `textvariable` property. When you assign a `tkinter` variable to this property, *the text of the label will automatically update whenever the variable changes*. You could get more complicated in what happens by using the `.trace()` method of `tkinter` variables to call a function whenever it is written.

Regarding minimum reproducible examples ... what I would have expected is a program which creates two frames, where clicking a button in one frame (`StartPage`) updates a string variable in the other frame (`SelectROIPage`), and , each with the same parent frame (`HRDetectorApp`). I wouldn't expect it to be more than 20-30 lines.

Comment: Hey, I updated my example - I used the same , global variable in both (as you suggested) and still no luck.. any idea what I'm still doing wrong?

Comment: @mimss I've updated my answer, hopefully that clarifies things. You don't need a global variable in the C/C++ sense. You need something more akin to a reference or pointer, so that both classes see the same data.

Comment: Great! One small issue - you said that if I use textvariable, the label will automatically update (as it does). However, I need to now pass this varible to OpenCv for a series of other tasks, BUT if I call the filename in SelectROIPage by calling:  filename = self.file.get() & it doesn't update. Is there a way I can force the variable to update the same way that it does when used in a label? THANK YOU! :)

Comment: I don't understand. In the example code I posted, self.filename will update, and self.filename.get() WILL return the updated filename. It is doing what you describe. In your code, you have multiple StringVariables, it's possible you're referencing the wrong one; without seeing updated code I can't say what's wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You can bind `<Expose>` event to the `SelectROIPage` class and update a label in the event callback (which is called when `SelectROIPage` is shown):

```
class SelectROIPage(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self,parent,controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self,parent)
        self.controller = controller
        self.startpg = self.controller.get_page(StartPage)
        tk.Label(self,text="Select a Region of Interest (R.O.I)", font=LARGE_FONT).pack(pady=10,padx=10)
        self.label = tk.Label(self) # label used to show the selected filename
        self.label.pack()
        self.bind('<Expose>', self.on_expose)

    def on_expose(self, event):
        self.label.config(text='Selected file: '+self.startpg.filename.get())
```

Comment: Would that trigger when raising above another frame? "This event occurs whenever at least some part of your application or widget becomes visible after having been covered up by another window." It's not another window covering the widget, but another widget...

Comment: Yes, it will be triggered when it is raising above another frame as long as it is covered by another frame before.  If it is already on the top, then no.

Comment: I tried this solution and when running my code, it just prompts the askopenfile dialog to popup BEFORE I click the button - any idea why?

Comment: @mimss I used your updated code with my solution and did not have the mentioned issue.

Comment: @mimss Also you should not create `Tk()` instance inside `openFile()` function.  Remove `root = tk.Tk()` and `root.update_idletasks()` from `openFile()`.