# displaying information on another frame? (tkinter python)

Tags: python, tkinter

so there is this stackoverflow question:

[Switch between two frames in tkinter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7546050/switch-between-two-frames-in-tkinter)

Which looks like a beautiful basis for building an application. But what if on startPage i want to have multiply buttons, and display the appropriate data on PageOne? Here is my attempt:

```
import tkinter as tk
from functools import partial

characters = {"character1": "abc", "character2": "def", "character3": "ghi", "character4": "jkl", "character5": "mnp", "character6": "qrs" }

class AdventureGame:
    ''' controller for managiging frames '''
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        self.frames = {}
        for F in (StartGame,ShowCharacters,CharacterDetail):
            frame = F(parent=master, controller=self)
            self.frames[F.__name__] = frame
            frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")
        ''' rais the first frame '''
        self.raise_frame("StartGame")

    def raise_frame(self,page_name):
        ''' raise a frame '''
        frame = self.frames[page_name]
        frame.tkraise()

    def lower_frame(self,page_name):
        ''' lower a frame '''
        frame = self.frames[page_name]
        frame.lower()

class StartGame(tk.Frame):
  ''' introduction screen of the game '''
  def __init__(self, parent, controller):
    super(StartGame,self).__init__(parent)
    self.controller = controller
    ''' introduction text '''
    tk.Label(self, text="welcome to this game").grid()
    tk.Button(self, text="next", command=lambda: controller.raise_frame("ShowCharacters")).grid()

class ShowCharacters(tk.Frame):
  ''' main frame, overview of all pokemon '''
  def __init__(self, parent, controller):
    super(ShowCharacters,self).__init__(parent)
    self.controller = controller
    for row, character in enumerate(characters):
      name_label = tk.Label(self, text=characters[character])
      name_label.grid(row=row,column=0)
      info_button = tk.Button(self, text="view info", command=partial(self.switch,character))
      info_button.grid(row=row,column=1)

  def switch(self, character):
    test = self.controller.raise_frame("CharacterDetail")

class CharacterDetail(tk.Frame):
    ''' detail view of pokemon '''
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        super(CharacterDetail,self).__init__(parent)
        self.controller = controller
        tk.Button(self, text="back", command=lambda: controller.lower_frame("CharacterDetail")).grid()

     # somehow display characters name here
    def showdetail(self):
        tk.Label(self, text="test").grid()

def main():
    root = tk.Tk()
    app = AdventureGame(root)
    root.mainloop()
main()
```

It feels like the the key is in the controller, as explained here:

[How to get variable data from a class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32212408/how-to-get-variable-data-from-a-class)

It just feels like i am missing something, does someone have an idea? Or am i thinking in the wrong direction all together?

If i try to show the detail:

```
def switch(self, character):
    test = self.controller.raise_frame("CharacterDetail")
    CharacterDetail.showdetail(self)
```

it shows up at the ShowCharacters frame rather then the CharacterDetail frame

I guess because `self` is the frame, which is `self` from ShowCharacters

I need to do something with the controller, but my mind just goes blank

So now i pass information to the controller:

```
import tkinter as tk
from functools import partial

characters = {"character1": "abc", "character2": "def", "character3": "ghi", "character4": "jkl", "character5": "mnp", "character6": "qrs" }

class AdventureGame:
    ''' controller for managiging frames '''
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        self.frames = {}
        for F in (StartGame,ShowCharacters,CharacterDetail):
            frame = F(parent=master, controller=self)
            self.frames[F.__name__] = frame
            frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")
        self.app_data = {"test": "test"}
        ''' rais the first frame '''
        self.raise_frame("StartGame")

    def raise_frame(self,page_name):
        ''' raise a frame '''
        frame = self.frames[page_name]
        frame.tkraise()

    def lower_frame(self,page_name):
        ''' lower a frame '''
        frame = self.frames[page_name]
        frame.lower()

class StartGame(tk.Frame):
  ''' introduction screen of the game '''
  def __init__(self, parent, controller):
    super(StartGame,self).__init__(parent)
    self.controller = controller
    ''' introduction text '''
    tk.Label(self, text="welcome to this game").grid()
    tk.Button(self, text="next", command=lambda: controller.raise_frame("ShowCharacters")).grid()

class ShowCharacters(tk.Frame):
  ''' main frame, overview of all pokemon '''
  def __init__(self, parent, controller):
    super(ShowCharacters,self).__init__(parent)
    self.controller = controller
    for row, character in enumerate(characters):
      name_label = tk.Label(self, text=characters[character])
      name_label.grid(row=row,column=0)
      info_button = tk.Button(self, text="view info", command=partial(self.switch,character))

      info_button.grid(row=row,column=1)

  def switch(self, character):
    test = self.controller.raise_frame("CharacterDetail")
    CharacterDetail.example(self)

class CharacterDetail(tk.Frame):
    ''' detail view of pokemon '''
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        super(CharacterDetail,self).__init__(parent)
        self.controller = controller
        tk.Button(self, text="back", command=lambda: controller.lower_frame("CharacterDetail")).grid()
    def example(self):
        tk.Label(self, text=self.controller.app_data["test"]).grid()


def main():
    root = tk.Tk()
    app = AdventureGame(root)
    root.mainloop()
main()
```

the label is still on the wrong frame, how can i get access to the right self so i can add the label to the right frame?

Comment: What's the question? You made an attempt, what's the result of that attempt? Is it not working? What is it doing differently than you expect?

Comment: # somehow display characters name here, i put this comment here. I somehow need to create a label which is added CharacterDetail frame.

Comment: i can't edit comments, that is bad. Anyway, i tried to add a method to CharacterDetail, but this wasn't working, i don't understand how i can access the frame

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you call `CharacterDetail.example(self)` in function `switch(...)` of class `ShowCharacters`, `self` will be class `ShowCharacters`.  Therefore the label created in function `example(self)` of class `CharacterDetail` will be in `ShowCharacters` frame.

Try:

- return the raised frame in function `raise_frame(...)` of class `AdventureGame`:

  ```
  def raise_frame(self, page_name):
      frame = self.frames[page_name]
      frame.tkraise()
      return frame   # return the raised frame
  ```
- modify function `switch(...)` of class `ShowCharacters`:

  ```
  def switch(self, character):
      frame = self.controller.raise_frame("CharacterDetail")
      frame.example()
  ```

Comment: Awesome, thank you so much, exactly what i needed. Good explanation, makes perfect sense! Thanks to you i can move on, you made someone's day :)