# Python TkInter Setting entry text from external function

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, python-module, tkinter-entry

I am making a GUI and to tidy it up, I'm looking into the possibility of pulling the core functions out into an external script, and having the main GUI call this.

The external module needs to be able to read widget data, and manipulate it.

So for example:

I have a script that has the base of the GUI and when ran, opens it up.

I have another script, inside a folder, which **will** contain the modules to make the GUI function.

The main GUI script needs to be able to call these modules/functions, and they need to be able to edit the widgets.

I have done some research and none of it is helping, most of the questions are about functions that are in the main script, and I already know how to do this.

**Main GUI Script**

```
import os, sys, ttk, pyodbc

from Tkinter import *
import Utils.Common as Common

class GUI:
    def __init__(self, *args):
        self.style = ttk.Style()
        font = "TkDefaultFont"

        root.title(uiTitle)
        root.iconbitmap(uiIcon)
        root.geometry(uiGeometry)

        self.connectBtn = ttk.Button(root, width=65)
        self.connectBtn.configure(text="Connect", command=Common.connectCleardox)
        self.connectBtn.grid(row=0, columnspan=4)

        self.exampleEnt = Entry(root, width=30)
        self.exampleEnt.grid(row=1, columnspan=4)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = Tk()
    GUI(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

**Utils/Common.py**

```
import tkMessageBox
from Tkinter import *

sys.path.insert(0, r'\\cd3\IT\Python\#PythonLibraries\Modules')
from CommonDB import Database

def connectCleardox():
    try:
        cleardoxConnection = Database.ConnectDatabase(Database(r"\\cd3\IT\Python\#PythonLibraries\ConfigFiles\Cleardox\Cleardox ConfigFile.json"))
        exampleEnt.insert(0, 'Success') #The widget from the GUI
    except Exception as e:
        tkMessageBox.showerror('uiTitle', "Database connection failed.\n\n%s" % (e))
        exampleEnt.insert(0, 'Fail') #The widget from the GUI
        return
```

Please let me know if I am being too vague, or not giving enough description.

Thank you all for your time.

Dylan.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get variable data from a class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32212408/how-to-get-variable-data-from-a-class)

Comment: So, your exact question is? Perhaps you could take a look over the MVC architecture pattern, I think it could help you to have a wider view of the system and properly structure your application.

Comment: Are you receiving a specific error message when trying to do this? What is your exact question that you need help with?

Comment: Does your utils folder contain an `__init__.py` file?

Comment: @danlor My exact question is how do I manipulate an Tkinter Object from an external module.

Comment: @scotty3785 I'm not receiving an error, please refer to my above comment.

Comment: @scotty3785 I do have an init file in my modules folder yeah, the import works fine, this is not the problem. Sorry for any inconvenience.

Comment: @DylanLogan Got it. You need to pass the connectCleardox function the tkinter widget so that it knows what `exampleEnt` is. `exampleEnt` isn't in the scope of the connectCleardox function so you need to tell it where it is.

Comment: @DylanLogan Then I recommend you to check out MVC, again.