# Python - accessing a local variable from another class

Tags: python, class, inheritance, tkinter, frames

I have tried to condense the code down as much as possible to make it clear what I am asking...

**I have a variable called `chosen_name`, determined in a class called `booking_frame`, that I would like to access in the `calendar_frame` class.**

Therefore, it would be obvious for `calendar_frame` to inherit the attributes of `booking_frame` - however, I believe (I'm probably completely wrong lol) that `calendar_frame` has to inherit the characteristics of `Frame` so that the whole program functions correctly.

The reason that `calendar_frame` is a completely separate class is so that it can appear as a different frame.

Extremely grateful for any help given :)

```
# import tkinter modules
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
import tkinter.font as tkFont
from PIL import ImageTk, Image
from tkcalendar import *



# define self
class tkinterApp(Tk):

    def __init__(self,*args, **kwargs):

        Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        # creating a container
        container = Frame(self)
        container.pack(side = "top", fill = "both", expand = True)

        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight = 1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight = 1)

        # initialising frames to an empty array
        self.frames = {}

        menu_bar = Menu(container)
        main_menu = Menu(menu_bar)

        menu_bar.add_cascade(label="Main Menu", menu=main_menu)
        main_menu.add_command(label="Welcome page", command=lambda: self.show_frame(welcome_frame))
        main_menu.add_command(label="Book a vehicle", command=lambda: self.show_frame(booking_frame))
        main_menu.add_command(label="Register as new user", command=lambda: self.show_frame(register_frame))

        Tk.config(self, menu=menu_bar)

        for F in (welcome_frame, booking_frame, register_frame, calendar_frame):
            frame = F(container, self)
            self.frames[F] = frame
            frame.grid(row = 0, column = 0, sticky = "nsew")

        self.show_frame(welcome_frame)

    def show_frame(self, cont):
        frame = self.frames[cont]
        frame.tkraise()


class welcome_frame(Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        Frame.__init__(self, parent)

        welcome = Label(self, text="Hello, please use the menu above to navigate the interface")
        welcome.grid(row=0, column=4, padx=10, pady=10)

class register_frame(Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):

        Frame.__init__(self, parent)

        register_label = Label(self, text="New user - enter your details below to use the Collyer's car park.")
        register_label.grid()


class booking_frame(Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        Frame.__init__(self, parent)

        chosen_name = "Steve"


class calendar_frame(Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        Frame.__init__(self, parent)

    print(booking_frame.chosen_name)


app = tkinterApp()
app.geometry("1000x800")
app.title("Collyer's Car Park")
app.mainloop()
```

Comment: 1. Look for some resources on the scope of variables. `chosen_name = "Steve"` sets a _local variable_ in the `booking_frame` constructor. It doesn't exist before the constructor is called, or after it runs. 2. Even if you changed it to `self.chosen_name = "Steve"` to make it an instance variable, an instance of `calendar_frame` has no relation to an instance of `booking_frame`. 3. You can have `calendar_frame` inherit `booking_frame` if that's what you want to do. There's no rule that says inheritance only works for one generation.

Comment: Please supply the expected [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (MRE).    You have a lot of irrelevant code in a post that asks only about scoping and cross-class capabilities.  Remove the Tkinter references and all of the GUI overhead.  Remove the extra classes.  *Then* describe just how you want to access the variable in another class.  Is that a method, an assignment to a class attribute, or other use?

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/a/32213127/7432

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to change local variable `chosen_name` to instance variable `self.chosen_name` inside `booking_frame` class, otherwise it cannot be accessed outside the class:

```py
class booking_frame(Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        Frame.__init__(self, parent)

        self.chosen_name = "Steve"  # changed to instance variable
```

Then you can access it via `controller.frames[booking_frame].chosen_name` inside `calendar_frame` class:

```py
class calendar_frame(Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        Frame.__init__(self, parent)

        print(controller.frames[booking_frame].chosen_name)
```

Answer (score 0):

Inheritance is to model relationships of objects which behave the same ("IS A" relationship). It is not meant to share data between objects.

A possible solution to your problem is to use a third object, that would be shared
between `booking_frame` and `calendar_frame`.

This object can be a Python dictionary for example ; you can pass it to all your
"frame" objects, or you can maybe decide to have it global (not very academic, for sure, but quick and dirty):

```py
GLOBAL_STATE = {}

class booking_frame(Frame):
    ...
    GLOBAL_STATE["chosen_name"] = "Steve"

class calendar_frame(Frame):
    ...
    print(GLOBAL_STATE.get("chosen_name"))
```

I hope you can see now how you can refactor your code to share data between those objects.

Comment: Thanks @mguijarr

I did as you said, but when I call `controller.show_frame(calendar_frame)` within the `booking_frame`, I get an error: `KeyError: <class '__main__.calendar_frame'>`.