# How do I pass variables in different classes?

Tags: python

I am having trouble with passing the variables into different classes. I am a beginner. I am trying to get the entry box to pass the textvariable which is self.margaritapizza(). However, when I try run it, it says 'nextage' has no attribute to 'margaritapizza'. So not sure how to pass the variable to different classes. I am using tkinter and it is in visual studio code if that helps.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import IntVar

class SampleApp(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        container = tk.Frame(self)
        container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        self.margaritapizza = IntVar()

        self.frames = {}
        for F in (StartPage, nextpage):
            page_name = F.__name__
            frame = F(parent=container, controller=self)
            self.frames[page_name] = frame
            frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")

        self.show_frame("StartPage")

    def show_frame(self, page_name):
        frame = self.frames[page_name]
        '''Show a frame for the given page name'''

        frame.tkraise()

class StartPage(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent, bg='#3d3d5c')
        self.controller = controller

        heading_label = tk.Label(self,
                             text="start page",
                             font=('arial', 45, 'bold'),
                             foreground='#ffffff',
                             background='#3d3d5c')
        heading_label.pack(pady=25)

        def next():
            controller.show_frame('nextpage')
        next_button = tk.Button(text="start page",command=next).pack

class nextpage(tk.Frame,SampleApp):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent, bg='#3d3d5c')
        self.controller = controller

        heading_label = tk.Label(self,
                                 text="start page",
                                 font=('arial', 45, 'bold'),
                                 foreground='#ffffff',
                                 background='#3d3d5c')
        heading_label.pack(pady=25)

        entry = tk.entry(borderwidth=2,width=15,textvariable=self.margaritapizza).pack

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = SampleApp()
    app.mainloop()
```

Comment: That's quite a lot of code, most of which I assume is irrelevan to the question. Can you please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so others can reproduce this problem easily?

Comment: I have changed it

Comment: Unfortunately, I get this error which is '_tkinter.tkapp' object has no attribute 'margaritapizza'. I do appreciate the help though. I did update the code so you can see what I did wrong if that helps

Comment: Try ```entry = tk.entry(borderwidth=2,width=15,textvariable=SampleApp().margaritapizza).pack``` and you can change it back to ```class nextpage(tk.Frame)```

Comment: Unfortunately, that didn't work. A bunch of errors in the terminal came up. I kept repeating this:  import tkinter as tk.py", line 52, in __init__    
    entry = tk.Entry(borderwidth=2,width=15,textvariable=SampleApp().margaritapizza)
  File "c:\Users\Joshu\OneDrive\Documents\Kate's Pizza\import tkinter as tk.py", line 19, in __init__    
    frame = F(parent=container, controller=self)

Comment: @Mark your suggestion would create a second instance of `SampleApp()` which almost certainly is the wrong thing to do.

Comment: Does this help answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33646605/how-to-access-variables-from-different-classes-in-tkinter Or this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32212408/how-to-get-variable-data-from-a-class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, `nextpage` should definitely *not* inherit from `SampleApp`. So, change the definition to:

```
class nextpage(tk.Frame):
```

Second, `margaritapizza` is an attribute of `SampleApp`, so you need to refer to it via the instance of `SampleApp`. In your case, `self.controller` is that instance, so you can use `self.controller.margaritapizza`.

There are other problems with how you define the entry, I'll fix them as well:

```
self.entry = tk.Entry(self, borderwidth=2,width=15,textvariable=self.controller.margaritapizza)
self.entry.pack()
```